# Plotting Marginal effects of interactions with continuous and dummy

Tags: plot, interaction, marginal-effects

I have a doubt about my homework on how to plot multiple interactions and I would be very grateful if anyone could help. I know this is a popular topic, but I have not seen questions addressing my specific problem. I hope is not a repetition

I have a model with 3 explanatory variables and two interactions. Two variables are continuous and one is a dummy. I would like to plot into a single image the marginal effect of the three interactions. 
the model is something like this

y = a+ b_1c1 + b_2c2 + b_3d + b_4c1c2 + b_5c1d

In sum, I have one continuous variable (c1), that is interacted both with the other continuous variable (c2) and the dummy variable (d).
The code below uses data from the MASS package to allow a reproducible example.

```
library(interplot) 
library(MASS) # to take the dataset from 
data<- cars93
library(interplot)  # for plotting interations
```

and I create my model

```
model<- lm(Price ~ Horsepower*EngineSize # c1*c2 interaction
 + Horsepower*Man.trans.avail, #c1*d interaction
 data = data)
```

I would like to plot the estimated effects of the `Horsepower` on `price` as a function of the `EngineSize` for `Man.trans.avail`=0 (No),
 and plot that same conditional effect of `Horsepower` on `price` as a function of the `EngineSize` for `Man.trans.avail`=1 (Yes). Possibly putting them into the same plot.

Using the `interplot` function I am able to see the conditional `Horsepower` on `price` as a function of the `EngineSize` but without controlling for `Man.trans.avail`

```r
interplot(m=model, var1 = "Horsepower", var2 = "EngineSize", hist = TRUE)
```

The result plots the marginal effect line of `Horsepower` and `EngineSize`, however, is not able to plot two lines for different values of `Man.trans.avail` and I was wondering whether you had some idea on how to plot marginal effects in similar circumstances.

I thank you a lot in advance for your replies